# How many colors in the colorbuffer of OpenGL ES we need?

Tags: opengl-es

If I have a cube mesh in OpenGL ES and I want to have a flat color for each side of the cube so that each side has a different color, do I need to specify color per vertex or color per triangle or color per side? 
This 2 lines of code:

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorBuffer);

are related to this question.

How OpenGL ES knows which color I specified matches with which side of the cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colours should be specified per-vertex, but as each face has a different colour, you are not going to be able to share vertices between faces. Instead of drawing a cube (8 vertices, 8 colours, 12 triangles), draw 6 quads that just happen to have coincident vertex positions (24 vertices, 24 colours, 12 triangles)

Edit: a quad is just 2 triangles that share some vertices. For example, a quad covering the unit square (in 2D) could have a vertex array and triangle index array like so:

```
// bottom left, top left, bottom right, top right order
float[] verts = new float[]{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
// anti-clockwise vertex order
int[] tris = new int[]{ 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 };
```

Comment: But Quads are not supported in OpenGL ES. Could you clarify your answer in light of this limitation of OpenGL ES?